# How to Change a value of a control from a different program(process)

Tags: winapi, c++builder

I would like to write a program, which lets me change a values in text box of different program, or automatically copy a values from one program to another.

I found a way to get hWnd to most (no idea if all of them) of controls in targer program, and to point them with mouse cursor. I made a simple struct to do so, and an array of it

```
struct hWndpointer
   {
   HWND hWnd;
   AnsiString text;
   };

hWndpointer tbl[250];
```

The EnumWindowProc and EnumChildWindowProc loads handles and text of the window into the array and into the list control in my program, so i can click an item on the list (or select it with keyboard) and the cursor points the control (like button or textbox) like expected... Unfortunately there are some controls with no text (or rather GetWindowText returns no text) so there is no way to identify the control.

The question is:
Is there any way to get/read a NAME of the control?
Is there any way to get/read and set a specyfic value like 'enabled' or 'text' or 'value'?

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: 'Name' of the control, is something invented in Windows Forms, and is stored on the CLR object representing the Win32 control. So if your target application is not .NET application, it's controls have no `Name`s, and if it is, you cannot retrieve this property using Win32 calls.

Comment: `Name` is also a construct of the VCL (the OP is using C++Builder).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` to send `WM_GETTEXT`, `WM_SETTEXT`, `WM_ENABLE` to windows owned by other processes.  (`SendMessage` for queries, `PostMessage` for write-only actions)

Often the child ID will be used to identify subwindows (especially in a dialog), but it's also possible for a program to rely purely on the dynamic `HWND` values, in which case you'll have to fall back to window positions to differentiate.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, i can get an ID of all controls in the "queried program", add it to corresponding item in my tbl of hWndVector (modyfing the struct first, ofcourse) and then using Send/PostMessage to change the values right?? I will try it right away, thx :D

Comment: @Qrchack: For that, you'll probably want `SendDlgItemMessage`.  Or `GetDlgItem` which gives you the `HWND` for the child window / control.  To read a child window's control ID, there's `GetDlgCtrlID` (if you found a child window `HWND` from mouse coordinates or something).  Spy++ should also show you control IDs.

Comment: One more Question: Is an ID a constant, i mean won't it change every time I run "queried program"? So i could write them down into some .ini file or even hardcode in my program (hardcode may be convenient 'cos my program will be used only to read/write data out/into a specific program)

Comment: Control IDs are constant.  But if the target program isn't using them internally, they may all be zero.  Control IDs are most commonly used along with dialog resources.

Comment: And if your target program is a .NET program, the IDs are NOT constant. Be careful.

Comment: what format(i don't know how to name it) the hWND have? is it simply a double? can it be converted to string and displayed in text field or label? After some thinking, there is no need to remember IDs, as i can make "quick intialization" by pointing the controls i need by mouse and read their hWnd or ID or whatever. The point of my program is to move the data automatically, so there would be no need to do so manually. time lost for manual intialisation will pay back after two sets of data moved... and there are hundreds of such sets.

Comment: IT WORKS !!!! Thank You very much:D Should i insert my code (after i clean up the mess ;) ) as an reply for the future wanderers of WINAPI world?

Comment: In addition to what @BenVoigt said, VCL controls in C++Builder and Delphi also do not use Control IDs at all, either, not even for dialogs.

Comment: @Qrchack: an `HWND` is a handle to a wnidow object in the OS.  It is not a number.  If you have an `HWND` to a control, you do not need to use an ID to communicate with it or manipulate it.  IDs are only meaningful if you are sending messages to a parent dialog window where the controls have IDs that are relative to that window.

Comment: well, language boundaries prevent me from express myself clearly ;)

Comment: When i list controls (and "show" them in the listbox) from the "target program", many of them don't have text or rather GetWindowText returns nothing. So in addition to that i get the x.y position of a control, so selecting an item in the listbox, points mouse on the corresponding control. However this was not enough, so i get ID which are displayed in the listbox. Now i can search my array tbl[250]) for the IDs (i've added int ID to the structure) and when found i take the hWnd and use it with Send/PostMessage.

Comment: I understand, that hWnd is a handle, however it have to have some numerical value which could be displayed right? If yes, i wouldn't need to read an ID, which as you say, can be allways 0, or not used at all. The hWnd, which i get from every control using enumchildwindows i allready have, so i thought it is possible to somehow display it in the textfield or label. Anyway - ID works, and i'm allready happy ;)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Is there any way to read/get a NAME of a control? This would be most usefull in my scenario i think. And by name i mean the text value set in object.properties in c++builder

Comment: @Qrchack: An `HWND` can be converted to a pointer-sized integer.  It may not BE a pointer, but it's the same size and conceptually similar.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - that is what i meat, thx ;) I understand that it wouln't be used as a handle anymore, but it is unique as long as the control is in memory, and can be used to visually identyfi the control, right?

Comment: @Qrchack: I posted an answer showing one way to get a control's `Name` from a VCL app.  It requires writing code in the control's owning app, though.  If you are trying to retreive Names from apps you do not have the source code for, then you are out of luck, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the Win32 API's perspective, UI controls do not have Names, so you cannot ask the API to return the `Name` of a UI control in another process because such a value does not exist.  Names are strictly a feature of the UI framework being used by the app (VCL in the case of C++Builder), and you cannot directly access frameworks across process boundaries.  You would need cooperation from the control's owning app.

For instance, one way would be to have both apps call `RegisterWindowMessage()` to register a custom window message, then your app can post that message to the other app specifying the desired control's `HWND` and your own `HWND` as parameters.  The other app can then `SendMessage()` the control's `Name` back to your app's `HWND` using the `WM_COPYDATA` message, which you can use to update your list accordingly.

In the VCL framework, you can convert an `HWND` to a `TWinControl*` pointer using the `FindControl()` function.  It will return `NULL` if the `HWND` does not belong to the calling process, otherwise you can then copy the value from its `Name` property.  For example:

```
const UINT WM_GETCONTROLNAME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GetControlName");
const UINT WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GetControlName_Result");

#include <pshpack1.h>
struct sControlName
{
    HWND hWnd;
    int Length;
    char Value[1];
};
#include <poppack.h>

void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if ((Message.Msg == WM_COPYDATA) && (WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT != 0))
    {
        LPCOPYDATASTRUCT cds = (LPCOPYDATASTRUCT) Message.LParam;
        if (cds->dwData == WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT)
        {
            sControlName *pName = (sControlName*) cds->lpData;
            AnsiString sName(pName->Value, pName->Length);

            // locate pName->hWnd in your list and assign sName to it as needed...

            return;
        }
    }

    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}

void ___fastcall TMyForm::FillList()
{
    ...
    if (WM_GETCONTROLNAME != 0)
    {
        HWND TheControlHWND = ...;
        HWND OtherAppHWND = ...;
        PostMessage(OtherAppHWND, WM_GETCONTROLNAME, (WPARAM)TheControlHWND, (LPARAM)this->Handle);
    }
    ...
}
```

.

```
const UINT WM_GETCONTROLNAME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GetControlName");
const UINT WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GetControlName_Result");

#include <pshpack1.h>
struct sControlName
{
    HWND hWnd;
    int Length;
    char Value[1];
};
#include <poppack.h>

void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if ((Message.Msg == WM_GETCONTROLNAME) && (WM_GETCONTROLNAME != 0) && (WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT != 0))
    {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND) Message.WParam;

        TWinControl *Ctrl = FindControl(hWnd);
        if (Ctrl)
        {
            AnsiString sName = Ctrl->Name;

            std::vector<unsigned char> buffer((sizeof(sControlName) - 1) + sName.Length());
            sControlName *pName = (sControlName*) &buffer[0];

            pName->hWnd = hWnd;
            pName->Length = sName.Length();
            strncpy(pName->Value, sName.c_str(), pName->Length);

            COPYDATASTRUCT cds = {0};
            cds.dwData = WM_GETCONTROLNAME_RESULT;
            cds.cdData = buffer.size();
            cds.lpData = pName;

            SendMessage((HWND)Message.LParam, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)this->Handle, (LPARAM)&cds);
        }

        return;
    }

    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

Comment: I will look into that, thx. However, i don't have an access to the curce code, and what is worse (since IDs are not constant in .NET app) the program i querry is written in .NET. I wonder however how such lines of code are seen from windows and winapi perspective: `Edit1.text = "whatever"`; or: `Button2.left = Form1.width - (Button2.width-20);`? They are passed somehow to windows "core" so, they need to be uniquely identified, right? I don't really need a name. Only some identyficator (whatevr it is)which will be unique inside the process so i can read it and use it later.

Comment: Again, stop using control IDs, regardless of what UI framework is used in the app.  If you have an `HWND` to a control, that is all you need. I can't speak for .NET, but in VCL setting the `Text` property sends a `WM_SETTEXT` message to the control's window procedure, and setting the `Left` property issues a call to the Win32 API `SetWindowPos()` function.

Comment: I allready stopped ;) and this is not what i mean. I understand that hwnd is all what i need. However... After i querry the program for control hWnds, and put them all into my array, i cannot say, basing solely on hWnd which control is which. So i use hwnd to get controls coordinates, and point the selected control with mouse. Problem is, until i point it with mouse i won't know which i will point. And i would like to identify the control some other way. After i did that it's ok, i know that the textfield i want do edit is under (for example) item 34. but item number 34 means nothing,

Comment: and after i reload the program the item number 34 may point on completely different control. I cannot use the coordinates as identifier, becaues when i move te window coordinates will be different, right? so what i need is unique identifier wchich will be allways the same. It doesn't have to be ID (which is allways different in .NET) it don't have to be name.

Comment: Chmm... it seems i was wrong. enumerating controls seems to return allways the same order. I tried to enumerate after restarting the program and on the different machine. Is it a coincidence, or enumerating children windows have some "inside" order? If yes, than finally i have the identyficator i need :D

Comment: There is no "unique" identifier for most controls, at least from the API perspective.  If you rely on client coordinates and not screen coordinates, then they are relative to the control's parent window, and thus do not (usually) change.  If the UI is not dynamically changing, then you can usually just rely on the parent/child window relationships and sibling window orderings by themselves to find the windows you want to interact with.